# I'm using marker on google map it doesn't update or not moving while i'm walking

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

*I'm using marker on  google map it doesn't update or not moving while i'm walking.. I want that marker to move as i walk...

*I need to use Network location while gps location not available then ultimately i need to use GPS location when it's available...

**GetandGiveLocation.java**

```
 public class GetandGiveLocation extends Service implements LocationListener 
{
        private final Context mContext;     
        // flag for GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;     
        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean canGetLocation = false;

        Location location; // location
        double latitude; // latitude
        double longitude; // longitude

        // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES =0; // 10 meters

        // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 2seconds

        // Declaring a Location Manager
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GetandGiveLocation(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();
        }

        public Location getLocation() {
            try {

                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

                String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    // First get location from Network Provider
                 if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                bestProvider,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {


                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    bestProvider,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }

                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;
        }

        /**
         * Stop using GPS listener
         * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
         * */
        public void stopUsingGPS(){
            if(locationManager != null){
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GetandGiveLocation.this);
            }      
        }

        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         * */
        public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude(){
            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         * @return boolean
         * */
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
         * */
        public void showSettingsAlert(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }

    <code>}</code>

    <strong>GoogleMapViewer.java </strong>

    <code>
    public class GoogleMapViewer extends Activity {

        GetandGiveLocation currentlocation;
        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.googlemap);

            try {

                // Grabbing location

                retrievelocation();
                // Loading map

                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void retrievelocation() {

            currentlocation = new GetandGiveLocation(GoogleMapViewer.this);

            if (currentlocation.canGetLocation) {

                latitude = currentlocation.getLatitude();
                longitude = currentlocation.getLongitude();
            }

        }

        private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();

                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

                MarkerOptions marker;

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).tilt(0).zoom(12)
                        .build();

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                marker = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title("title").snippet("Just a snippet");

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "latitude" + latitude + "longitude" + longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Markers don't move with you, they just mark location. You need to remove your location marker on updates, and remark yourself in your current position. You have nothing in your onLocationChanged methodology, so when your location changes, you aren't doing anything.

Comment: thanks.. do you have any idea about how to get best location of user?

Comment: To keep updated locations of your user, in onLocationChanged update your longitude and latitude coordinates of your user using location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude(). That is how you keep the (best) location of the user. The method onLocationChanged is what allows you to keep your locations current.

Comment: No worries, as future reference if want to let a stack overflow user know that you are responding to their comments you can use the @userName tag. That way they will get a notification and it will be easier for them to help. For example, you could have tagged me in your response comment, '@zgc7009 thank you so much for helping me..' :)